# Display custom post type with shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode

I have made a custom post type for my WordPress Theme and a page where the custom post types are displayed.
But does anyone know how to make a shortcode that displays posts of a custom post type?

Comment: Possible yes, but what have tried yourself to solve this issue and where are you stuck

Answer (score 5):

I think, basically your question is, how to query posts of a custom post type in a shortcode. You should have a look into the WP_Query section of WordPress:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

In my example code I create a shortcode, which shows the title of the latest published posts of the type 'my-custom-post-type':

```
<?php
    add_shortcode( 'shortcodename', 'display_custom_post_type' );

    function display_custom_post_type(){
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'my-custom-post-type',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );

        $string = '';
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $query->have_posts() ){
            $string .= '<ul>';
            while( $query->have_posts() ){
                $query->the_post();
                $string .= '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
            }
            $string .= '</ul>';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        return $string;
    }
?>
```

Since a shortcode is executed in the loop, you should use `wp_reset_postdata()` after you are done with your query, so the Main Loop works again like expected. More information for this function will be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata

I hope, this gives you a headstart.

Comment: you should use `wp_reset_postdata` after a secondary loop. `wp_reset_query` is only necessary to restore the `$wp_query` global, which was not overwritten in this case. `wp_reset_query` also calls `wp_reset_postdata` internally, which is why it works here, but is unnecessary.